# How to override Joda-Time GSP tag output

Tags: grails, groovy, jodatime, gsp

I am using the Joda-Time plug-in for Grails, and so far it has been a huge help. A massive improvement over the Java Date/Callendar method. Anyway, I am rendering Period data using the  GSP tags as follows:

```
<joda:formatPeriod value="${ shift?.totalTime }" fields="hours,minutes" />
```

The tag renders the HTML as, `11 hours and 32 minutes`. That's great but I need to override the text and change it to `11hrs. 32min.`.

Does anyone have experience doing this? I haven't found any examples as I've Googled the interwebs. I think this would help many others, as well.

BTW: I am really grateful to the Joda-Time creators. It's one of the most useful libraries/plugins I've found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't concerned about localized text and will only have hours and minutes, then a simple solution would be to write your own little tag to do the formatting. Something like:

```
def formatPeriod = { attrs ->
    def periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSuffix("hrs.").appendSeparator(" ").appendMinutes().appendSuffix("min.").toFormatter()

    out << periodFormatter.print(attrs.value)
}
```

Here's sample output from a groovy shell:

```
groovy:000> period = new Period().withHours(11).withMinutes(32)
===> PT11H32M
groovy:000> formatter = PeriodFormat.wordBased()
===> org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter@6d2ddeee
groovy:000> formatter.print(period)
===> 11 hours and 32 minutes
groovy:000> periodFormatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSuffix("hrs.").appendSeparator(" ").appendMinutes().appendSuffix("min.").toFormatter()
===> org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatter@56048075
groovy:000> periodFormatter.print(period)
===> 11hrs. 32min.
```

Comment: This seems to be the best option going forward. Custom tags are relatively simple in Grails. My short-cut is to use the Period attributes directly: 

`${ shift?.totalTime?.hours }hrs. ${ shift?.totalTime?.minutes }min.` 

Sometimes the simplest answers are hidden right under our noses. Although, it's not exactly what I want. A custom tag will be the best long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code for the [PeriodTagLib](https://github.com/gpc/grails-joda-time/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/jodatime/taglib/PeriodTagLib.groovy) it appears to be delegating that to JodaTime's word based [PeriodFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormat.html#wordBased%28java.util.Locale%29) which by default is using the values from the [org.joda.time.format.message bundle](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/master/src/main/java/org/joda/time/format/messages.properties).

You could try defining those keys in your own message bundle in grails-app/i8n/messages.proprties but I doubt that would work.

You may have to edit the bundle from within the included sources. :/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm hoping this is a last-resort. I have been looking into the source and really hope I won't have to do that.